# How to properly flatmap three HTTP requests

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an app that makes 3 HTTP requests and each request relies on information from the others. Currently I am making the next request on success but that is inefficient. I did some research and found that I'm suppose to be using `flatmap` but the couple of ways I've tried dont make the http requests to the api

This is what I've tried but it returns nothing

```
return this.info.getLastRecord(this.station)
      .map((res: any) => res.json()
      .flatMap((info: any) => {
        return this.info.getQueue(this.lastID)
          .map((res: any) => {
            console.log(res.json());
          });
      }));
```

This doesnt work either

```
return this.info.getLastRecord(this.station)
    .map((res: any) => res.json()
    .flatMap((res: any) => {
    return this.info.getQueue(this.lastID)
        .map((res: any) => {
        console.log(res);
     });
   }));
```

This is how i'm currently making the calls

```
this.getInfoService.getLastRecord(this.station)
  .subscribe(
    (info) => {
      console.log("res", info);
    },
    (error: Response) => console.log(error),
    () => this.getQueue()
  );

getQueue() {
  this.info.getQueue(this.lastID)
  .subscribe(
    (info) => {
      console.log("getQueue", info);
    },
    (error: Response) => console.log(error),
    () => this.gHTDG())
}

getHookTypeDieGroup() {
this.info.getHookTypeDieGroup(this.profileCode)
  .subscribe(
    (info) => {
      console.log("GHTDG", info);
    },
    (error: Response) => console.log(error)
  );
}
```

info.service.ts

```
getLastRecord(station: string): any {
return this.http.get('http://API.app/getLastRecord/' + station)
  .map(
    (response: Response) => {
      return response.json().info;
    },
  ).share();
}

getQueue(lastID: number): any {
return this.http.get('http://API.app/getQueue/' + lastID)
  .map(
    (response: Response) => {
      return response.json().info;
    }
  )
  .share();
}

gHTDG(pCode: string): any {
return this.http.get('http://API.app/getHTDG/' + pCode)
  .map(
    (response: Response) => {
      return response.json().info;
    }
  ).share();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need them chained together in sequence I think switchMap is the operator you want.  I'm having a hard time following your logic, but I think it would look something like this:

```
this.getInfoService
    .getLastRecord(this.station)
    .switchMap(x => this.getQueue(x.(value from getLastRecord call)))
    .switchMap(x => this.getHookTypeDieGroup(x.(value from getQueue call))
    .subscribe(x => {  //Do something with final result });
```

Each switchMap will subscribe to the previous observable and feed it's result into the fat arrow function which will return a new observable.  The subscribe will be to the result of the final observable.

[Example can be found here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/bg0rnFtqlkOXKlzr3Dht?p=preview)

Comment: I created a plnkr and added it to the answer.  I think it's working the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think `concatMap` would be the operator for you, if you want to execute the 3 requests in an specific order after they complete consecutively. Foe example:

```
getLastRecord(station: string): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get(`http://API.app/getLastRecord/${station}`)
  .map(response => response.json().info)
  .catch(//handle error);
}

getQueue(lastID: number): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get(`http://API.app/getQueue/${lastID}`)
  .map(r=> r.json().info)
  .catch(//handle error);
}

gHTDG(pCode: string): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get(`http://API.app/getHTDG/${pCode}`)
  .map(response => response.json().info);
  .catch(//handle error)
}

concatenatedRequest(station: string): Observable<any>{
  return this.getLastRecord(station)
.concatMap(lastRecord=> this.getQueue(lastRecord.id))//lastRecord is the result from the previous getLastRecord request
.concatMap(queueData => this.gHTDG(queueData.pCode))//queueData is the result of the previous getQueue request
.catch(//handle error);
}
```

I haven't tried it but according to the docs that should work :D
For more info about the operator check the following [link](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html)

Comment: Are you getting errors or something? is any request sent to ths server? did you subcribed outside of the service right?